# How do I create this symbolic link in Unix?

Tags: symlink, path

I want to run gmake when I run make, so I am creating a symbolic link. My gmake is inside `/usr/local/dist`. My make is inisde `/usr/ccs/bin`.

Is this the correct command: `ln -s /usr/local/dist/gmake /usr/ccs/bin/make`

My confusion is, do I even care about `/usr/ccs/bin/make`? I am making a symbolic link so if I type "make" anywhere it should just run gmake at `/usr/local/dist` right?

So should the command be: `ln -s /usr/local/dist/gmake make`?

Comment: Check which command `make` points to at the moment. Try `which make` and then `ls -al <the folder given by previous command>`.  Some distros have make as a symlink to gmake as standard.

Comment: Make does not currently point to anything -- ie I don't see "make -> something_else"

Comment: The second way creates the link in the current directory.  So the effect it has depends what your last `cd` command was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link `gmake` into the `PATH` before `make`, e.g. in `/usr/bin`. Check where `make` is linked now (if it is): `type make`

If `/usr/bin` is earlier in the PATH than the directory in which `make` is found then you can link it there with this command:

```
ln -s /usr/local/dist/gmake /usr/bin/make
```

Maybe you have to overwrite an existing link to make. I am not sure though how safe that is against updates of the package.

Comment: Thank you! So yes I already had added gmake earlier in my PATH than make (thought this was needed for what I was doing). So here is my command then: "ln -s /usr/sfw/bin/gmake /usr/ccs/bin/make" -- when I try this command I get the message: "ln: cannot create /usr/ccs/bin/make: File exists"

Comment: @DemiSheep You shall not overwrite an existing file (if it is not a symlink). Is `/usr/ccs/bin` part of your `PATH`? What is the output of `type make`?

Comment: "type make" results in: "make is hashed (/usr/ccs/bin/make)"

Answer (score 4):

Symlinking system binaries is usually not the correct approach at all. This will cause untold complications later with other software that expects certain binary names to correspond to certain know behaviors. It sounds like what you want is an alias instead. In your shell run:

```
alias make=gmake
```

Now any time you type make, it will run gmake for you. To make this permanent, add that line to your shell's rc file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: That's an interesting thought and makes a lot of sense. So any script I run that calls make will be fine with the alias as well, correct? The reason I started down this road of creating a symlink is because the other machine has a symbolic link setup the way I was working on duplicating. Would the symlink be seen by all users on the system, where the alias would only be used by me?

Comment: @DemiSheep, no. aliases affect only interactive shells (and only those that read you ~/.bashrc).

Comment: @DemiSheep No, aliases affect your interactive shell, not scripts. You should _really_  be writing your scripts to call the binary you actually want. If you script expects the behavior of gmake rather than make, it should be calling gmake explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir -p ~/bin &&
  ln -s /usr/local/dist/gmake ~/bin/make &&
  PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

That way you have control over what process (those that have a `PATH` where you're `~/bin` is before `/usr/ccs/bin`) would invoke `gmake` upon `make`.

Comment: Not a very permanent effect though...

Comment: @HaukeLaging, well the point is you should not make it permanent. You don't want `gmake` to take over `make` as it would probably break things. If you still want to make it permanent (for your user), add the `PATH=~/bin:$PATH` to your `~/.profile`

Comment: OK, interesting point but that should be explained in the answer then.